# how to change the content of the select box?

Tags: javascript, php, html

i found a code that changes the options in the second select box depending on the chosen option in the first select box. it works in jsfiddle but when i try it in my laptop, it doesnt work , can you find out why? the javascript uses jquery 1.7.2 and i run it on mozilla.
heres the code

```
<select name="select1" id="select1">
<option value="1">Fruit</option>
<option value="2">Animal</option>
<option value="3">Bird</option>
<option value="4">Car</option>
</select>


<select name="select2" id="select2">
<option value="1">Banana</option>
<option value="1">Apple</option>
<option value="1">Orange</option>
<option value="2">Wolf</option>
<option value="2">Fox</option>
<option value="2">Bear</option>
<option value="3">Eagle</option>
<option value="3">Hawk</option>
<option value="4">BWM
<option>
</select>
```

Heres the javascript;

```
$("#select1").change(function() {
if ($(this).data('options') == undefined) {
/*Taking an array of all options-2 and kind of embedding it on the      select1*/
$(this).data('options', $('#select2 option').clone());
}
var id = $(this).val();
var options = $(this).data('options').filter('[value=' + id + ']');
$('#select2').html(options);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you just need to import jquery source code in your HTML code

Try adding this to your HTML file.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

It probably already works on jsfiddle as it was instructed to load an external dependency (jquery in this case).

Let me know if that solved your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Code looks okay. Are you sure you have the jQuery library included?